# Binomial distribution problem with inconsistent probability of occurrence

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains

```
| 0.4  | 0.5  | 0.3  | 0.4  | 0.5  |
| 0.4  | 0.5  | 0.3  | 0.4  | 0.5  |
| 0.4  | 0.5  | 0.3  | 0.4  | 0.5  |
| 0.4  | 0.5  | 0.3  | 0.4  | 0.5  |
```

In each cell of the matrix is the winning probability.
What is the probability that more than 4 cells will win if all cells are randomized at the same time.

Because each lattice has a different probability, I can't solve it with a binomial distribution, and then I can't figure out what I should do.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Do you step sequentially through each cell in the table (there are 20 cells
by the way)? The distribution will be given by a sum of different binomial
distributions: $8$ draws with $p=0.4$; $8$ draws with $p=0.5$ and $4$ draws
with $p=0.3$.

Comment: I don't understand : **Explain how is the "game" is played**, moreover with the right words : for example, what you call a grid is a box/cell, isn't it ? (the "grid" is made of 20 "cells"...).

Comment: Sorry for my poor English, I'll describe the problem from scratch

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly,  the probability of exactly $n$ winning cells is the coefficient of $x^n$ when $(0.7 +0.3 x)^4 (0.6 + 0.4 x)^8 (0.5 + 0.5 x)^8$ is expanded.  Maybe you can work with that.

Comment: @awkward I see we are on the same tracks...

Comment: By the way: do not feel complexed about your level in english. English is not either my mother language. Being at ease with a foreign language can take years. But consider using "Google Translate" which gives excellent results most of the time.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If "all cells are randomized" means they are permuted without changing the individual cell's "winning probablity", then that would not affect "the probability that more than $4$ cells will win.  So there is perhaps a different sense of "randomized" that you were thinking of.  Please clarify.

Comment: hi,hardmath i'm sorry that the description of my question bothered you, Jean Marie already gave me the answer I was looking for.You can revisit this description in light of the answers he gives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $4$, resp. $8$ and $8$ cells with probability $0.3$, resp. $0.4$ and $0.5$.

The number of successes is:

$$X=X_1+X_2+X_3 \tag{1}$$

where $X_1 \sim Bin(4,0.3), \ \ X_2 \sim Bin(8,0.4), \ \ X_3 \sim Bin(8,0.5), \ \ $

The PGF of a Bin(n,p) distribution is [$E(s^X)=(q+ps)^n$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Probability_Generating_Function_of_Binomial_Distribution).

Therefore, as a consequence of (1), due to the independence of the $X_i$, the PGF of $X$ is $E(s^X)=E(s^{X_1})E(s^{X_2})E(s^{X_3})$, i.e.,

$$(0.7+0.3s)^4(0.6+0.4s)^8(0.5+0.5s)^8=p_0+p_1s+p_2s^2+\cdots p_{20}s^{20}\tag{2}$$

where $p_k:=P(X=k)$.

These coefficients can be obtained using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+%280.7%2B0.3*s%29%5E4*%280.6%2B0.4*s%29%5E8*%280.5%2B0.5*s%29%5E8),

[image]

giving the final answer:

$$P(X>4)=1-P(X \le 4)=1-\sum_{k=0}^4 p_k \approx 1-0.0332812=0.9667188$$

**Remark:** $E(X)=4 \times 0.3 + 8 \times 0.4 + 7 \times 0.5=8.4$, this result being concordant with the fact that the most important values are $p_8$ and $p_{9}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer